# PieChartView in custom tableviewcell

Tags: swift, uitableview, charts

I have a tableview section with one cell (a custom tableviewcell). inside this custom tableviewcell i'm trying to put a pie chart. the piechartview shows up but the pie chart itself (with the data) doesn't show up. the custom cell is not receiving the 'properties' and 'values' data even though i set these in cellforrow function of the tableview when i create the custom cell. I'm doing everything programmatically, by the way.

i register the cell like so:

```
statisticsTable.register(PieChartCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId2")
```

and create the cell here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch headerTitles[indexPath.section]{
        case "Diet":
            let cell:PieChartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId2", for: indexPath) as! PieChartCell
            cell.properties = ["United States","Mexico","Canada","Chile"]
            cell.values = [1000.0,2000.0,3000.0,4000.0]
            return cell

        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
    }


}
```

No need to pay attention to the createPieChart() function in the below class because i have tested it with a non custom cell (UITableViewCell) and the pie chart showed up (i just cant get it to show up in the custom cell).

```
class PieChartCell:UITableViewCell{


var properties = [String]()
var values = [Double]()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


    var dietChart = PieChartView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:400,height:400))
    dietChart.backgroundColor = .clear

    createPieChart(chart: dietChart,property: properties, value: values) 

}


func createPieChart(chart:PieChartView,property:[String],value:[Double])  {
    var entries = [PieChartDataEntry]()
    for (index, value) in value.enumerated() {
        let entry = PieChartDataEntry()
        entry.y = value
        entry.label = property[index]
        entries.append( entry)
    }

    let set = PieChartDataSet( values: entries, label: nil)

    colors = [UIColor.green,UIColor.cyan,UIColor(red:218/255 ,green:165/255 ,blue:32/255,alpha:1.0 ),UIColor.blue,UIColor.red]

    set.colors = colors
    let data = PieChartData(dataSet: set)
    chart.data = data
    chart.noDataText = "No data available"
    chart.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    chart.backgroundColor = .clear
    let d = Description()
    d.text = ""
    chart.chartDescription = d
    chart.holeColor = UIColor(red:255,green:255,blue:255,alpha:0.5)
    self.addSubView(chart)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

So the question is how/when to properly set the 'properties' and 'values' variables of the custom cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your `PieChartView` and add it to your screen in `init` function. then on `cellForRow` you update its properties and not rerender your `PieChartView`.

1. Easiest solution will be to call `createPieChart()` after you set the properties in `cellForRow` (Don't forget to clear your cell and prepare it for reuse).
2. I would prefer to call `createPieChart()` on `awakeFromNib()` and implement another function to set the properties and rerender `PieChartView` on `cellForRow`.

Comment: makes sense. i went with option 1. refactored my code and it works now.

Comment: I am creating same table view cell with pie chart. I showing properly on table view cell but my pie chart have delegate methods (chartValueSelected and chartValueNothingSelected). I created extension for my main class. But how can i access mu specific pie chart on table view and set properties for that ??

Comment: When you implement chartValueSelected and chartValueNothingSelected you get the chartView right in this methods. we you can easily access the chartView. look at this signature for example:
`func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)`

Comment: @TalCohen in this method we are getting chartView of type ChartViewBase but i want to perform action of my pie chart view which is of type PieChartView.

Comment: If you’re using only PieChartView in every cell you can cast it as ‘chartView as! PieChartView’. If you use different charts you can check ‘if let pieChart = chartView as? PieChartView {‘ and use the casted pieChart variable.

Comment: @TalCohen thnx able to access my pie chart.